# How can I switch from xib file to viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, xib

When the image in the view I created with xib is clicked, I want it to go to the view controller in the storyboard. I tried segue-present and pushviewcontroller() but how can I do it?
Also, the delegate nil in the imageClicked() function is coming.delagate should not be nil
This is xib file:
[xib view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9yEV.png)

```
import UIKit
protocol BookDetailVideoViewDelegate : class {
    func videoOpen(value: Bool)
}

class BookDetailVideoViewController: UIViewController{

    weak var delegate : BookDetailVideoViewDelegate?
    var book : Book?
    var videoUrl = ""
    var url: URL?
    var index = 0
  
    @IBOutlet weak var bookImageView: UIImageView!
    //var book = self.book
    
    @IBOutlet weak var bookImageViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    

  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        } else {
            self.edgesForExtendedLayout = []
        }
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        //self.bookImageViewWidthConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.35
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

        if let url = self.url {
            self.bookImageView.kf.setImage(with: url)
        }
        
        self.bookImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        bookImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageClicked))
        bookImageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    
    deinit {
        self.url = nil
    }
    
    @objc func imageClicked(){
        print(delegate as Any)
        self.delegate?.videoOpen(value: true)  
    }
    func initializeView(url: URL, index: Int , book: Book) {

        self.index = index
        self.url = url
        self.book = book
        
    }
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    }
}
```

The view controller is like this:

```
import UIKit
import YoutubePlayer_in_WKWebView

class YoutubeVideoViewController: UIViewController , BookDetailVideoViewDelegate, WKYTPlayerViewDelegate {
    let myDelegate : BookDetailVideoViewController = BookDetailVideoViewController()
   
    var boolvalue = true
    var book : Book?
    
    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: WKYTPlayerView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        playerView.delegate = self
        myDelegate.delegate = self
        let mediakey = book!.mediaKey as String?
        playerView.load(withVideoId: mediakey!)
      
    }
    
    func videoOpen(value : Bool) {
    
        guard let ViewC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YoutubeVideoViewController") as? YoutubeVideoViewController else{return}
        ViewC.book = book
        ViewC.boolvalue = value
        
        self.present(ViewC, animated: true)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `BookDetailVideoViewController()` creates a new instance which is **not** the instance in the storyboard. You need the actual reference either with a segue or by instantiating the instance from the storyboard.

Comment: `myDelegate` is a new instance from `BookDetailVideoViewController` . And you are not setting delegate to any viewcontroller so your `delegate` is nil

Comment: So how should I write? I'm new to ios development. I think there is a way to switch from xib to storyboard.                                                                                                             I had defined a delegate named delegate in BookDetailVideoViewController. Then I called it self.delegate in imageClicked(). In other YoutubeViewcontrolller() I created it called myDelegate. How should I write it?

Comment: Think of it like a parent child relationship. You need to define the delegate in the child and give that delegate (like child.delegate = self) in the parent then call delegate.functionName in child's action

Comment: [delegate is nil here(BookDetailVideViewController())](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CyrB.png)
[I defined delegate in child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AkB7.png)
As you said, the child is **BookDetailVideoViewController()**. Parent is **YoutubeVideoViewController()**. I defined delegate in child and used **self.delegate?.videoOpen()** in imageClicked(). In Parent, I wrote **BookDetailVideoViewController().delegate = self** in viewDidload().

Comment: The problem is BookDetailVideoViewController().delegate is creates a new instanse from BookDetailVideoViewController. Thats why its still nil. You need to create the delegate with the instance you created when calling the child

Comment: Please re-read my first comment `BookDetailVideoViewController()` will never work because it creates a brand new instance which is different from the instance in the storyboard.